# What is the name of cyclopropane with a double bond?

Tags: nomenclature

I was drawing out all the isomers of $\ce{C5H8}$ and came upon two structures of cyclopropane attached with double bonds. The group is neither a methylene nor an ethyl... what is it? What are the names of these two molecules?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: ethylidenecyclopropane] Ethylidenecyclopropane

[image: vinylcyclopropane] Vinylcyclopropane (or Ethenylcyclopropane)

Comment: Note that these aren't the IUPAC names, care to add those as well? Also a bit about how the two functional groups have (common) names as ethylidene and vinyl respectively. Thanks :)

Comment: Ethylidenecyclopropane is the IUPAC name for that molecule. What else could you call it? See http://www.acdlabs.com/iupac/nomenclature/93/r93_271.htm. The vinyl substituent has been recently accepted by IUPAC (in the last 10 years), but I haven't found supporting proof on the web.

Comment: As a side note, IUPAC names are nice and all, but completely worthless if practicing chemists do not use them: 2-propanone, methanoic acid, and 1,2-didehydrobenzene are all significantly more frequently referred to by their common names of acetone, formic acid, and benzyne.

Comment: @Manish, as already noted, ["ethylidene" is in fact valid IUPAC nomenclature](http://www.chem.qmul.ac.uk/iupac/ions/RC811.html#p13).